# SQL 2008: Prevent Full-text lookup in query when not needed

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, full-text-search, short-circuiting

From working on this specific situation, it was news to me that the logic operators are not short circuited in SQL.

I routinely do something along these lines in the where clause (usually when dealing with search queries):

```
WHERE
   (@Description IS NULL OR @Description = myTable.Description)
```

Which, even if it's not short-circuited in this example, doesn't really matter.  However, when dealing with the fulltext search functions, it does matter.. If the second part of that query was `CONTAINS(myTable.Description, @Description)`, it wouldn't work because the variable is not allowed to be null or empty for these functions.

I found out the `WHEN` statements of `CASE` are executed in order, so I can change my query like so to ensure the fulltext lookup is only called when needed, along with changing the variable from null to `'""'` when it is null to allow the query to execute:

```
WHERE
   (CASE WHEN @Description = '""' THEN 1 WHEN CONTAINS(myTable.Description, @Description) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1)
```

The above code should prevent the full-text query piece from executing unless there is actually a value to search with.

My question is, if I run this query where @Description is `'""'`, there is still quite a bit of time in the execution plan spent dealing with clustered index seeks and fulltextmatch, even though that table and search does not end up being used at all: is there any way to avoid this?

I'm trying to get this out of a hardcoded dynamic query and into a stored procedure, but if the procedure ends up being slower, I'm not sure I can justify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into a scenario like this, this is what I ended up doing, which is pretty close to what M_M was getting at; I broke away the full-text pieces and placed them behind branches:

```
DECLARE @TableBfullSearch TABLE (TableAId int)
IF(@TableBSearchInfo IS NOT NULL)
   INSERT INTO @TableBfullSearch
   SELECT
      TableAId
   FROM
      TableB
   WHERE
   ...(fulltext search)...

DECLARE @TableCfullSearch TABLE (TableAId int)
IF(@TableCSearchInfo IS NOT NULL)
   INSERT INTO @TableCfullSearch
   SELECT
      TableAId
   FROM
      TableC
   WHERE
   ...(fulltext search)...

--main query with this addition in the where clause
SELECT
  ...
FROM
   TableA
WHERE
   ...
   AND (@TableBSearchInfo IS NULL OR TableAId IN (SELECT TableAId FROM @TableBfullSearch))
   AND (@TableCSearchInfo IS NULL OR TableAId IN (SELECT TableAId FROM @TableCfullSearch))
```

I think that's probably about as good as it'll get without some sort of dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but maybe something like this would work:

```
IF @Description = ''
BEGIN 
     SELECT ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SELECT ...
     WHERE CONTAINS(mytable.description, @Description)
END
```

That way you avoid mysql and also running the FT scan when it's not needed.

As a few general notes, I usually find `CONTAINSTABLE` to be a bit faster. Also, since the query plan is going to be very different whether you're using my solution or yours, watch out for [parameter sniffing](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/). Parameter sniffing is when the optimizer builds a plan based on a passed in specific parameter value.

Comment: That'll get a little dicey, since there are 2 of these optional look-ups in the query, so i'd end up with 4 branches